# Log in with SSH with a private key

Tags: ssh, private-key, openssh

I've been given by someone a private key to log into their machine with SSH. I got no public key, and the password authentication works. I added the key to /root/.ssh/id_rsa, but it still doesn't work. What am I missing? I thought I would have to get the public key from the private one, but I have no idea how to do that.
I cannot generate a new key pair, because I don't have writing permissions to that remote machine. I have to do it just with the private key.

Comment: First thing I would do is to run ssh with the verbose flag, -v. That should give you some idea of where the problem lies. If the matching public key is not already installed, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Well, can't I just generate the public key from the private key?

Comment: If you don't have write permission on the remote machine, what could you do with the public key if you had it?

Comment: I could log in. That's the end goal here. I need the public key to put it in `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. The public key is already there, on the remote machine, in `~/.ssh/authorized_hosts`, there's just no way for me to get there as I cannot log in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer:

1. First check if what you have is a private key (you will need the passcode for that):

   `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
2. Then generate the public side of the key and output it to id_rsa.pub

   `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`